# avoidin circular topic remapping

Tags: ros, roslaunch, remapping, topic, remap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.
I've got a problem with topic remapping. I have a node that publishes informations relative to a robot, and listens to the topics of the informations relative to other 3 robot of the same type. Something like:

publish on : /robot1/info
listens to: /robot2/info , /robot3/info, /robot4/info.

Now I want all the 4 robots to share the same code.

So, I want, for example, robot2 to publish on /robot2/info and to listen to /robot1/info (and to the other 2 robots of course)

In the launch file a used a classic remap in this way:
from="/robot1/info" to="/robot2/info" and
from="/robot2/info" to="/robot1/info"

but the result is that nothing changes and I think is due to some kind of circular remapping.

Any idea of how to address the problem?
Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63368/avoidin-circular-topic-remapping/) by [jacky_90](https://answers.ros.org/users/4309/jacky_90/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2013-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you've identified the heart of the problem: you're trying to remap the output of a node to the same name as one of its inputs.  Instead, try to leave each node's output alone, and only remap the inputs:

```
my_node:
  - publishes: infoOut
  - subscribes: infoIn1, infoIn2, infoIn3
```

```
<node name="node1" pkg="my_pkg" type="my_node" ns="robot1">
  <remap from="infoIn1" to="robot2/infoOut"/>
  <remap from="infoIn2" to="robot3/infoOut"/>
  <remap from="infoIn3" to="robot4/infoOut"/>
</node>

<node name="node2" pkg="my_pkg" type="my_node" ns="robot2">
  <remap from="infoIn1" to="robot1/infoOut"/>
  <remap from="infoIn2" to="robot3/infoOut"/>
  <remap from="infoIn3" to="robot4/infoOut"/>
</node>

...
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to put each node in a separate namespace, you can use the same approach as above, but remap each node's output into a node-specific name:

```
<remap from="infoOut" to="infoOut1"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4